# Losing Oauth Authorization When App Redirects to Page Tab

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, redirect, oauth, devise

I'm using the Oauth redirect authorization method to provide authorization for a page tab iframe application.

The flow works like this:

- User loads page tab (unauthorized)
- User clicks authorize link
- Authorization dialog takes over parent window
- Accepted authorization redirects to my application to register user account using authorized email.
- My application redirects back to the page tab
- Loading the page tab causes authorization to be lost, and the user sees the authorize link again. Rinse, repeat, no success.

Confusingly, the application works completely if instead of redirecting to the Facebook Page Tab, I redirect to any path in my application (ie. the root, the user's page, etc.). Only by setting the redirect to the Facebook Page Tab URL does the user get "booted".

Even stranger, if I keep redirection limited to my application, but simply load the Facebook Page Tab, the authorization is killed everywhere. Meaning, post-facebook-page-load, refreshing the application off-Facebook will prompt the user to authorize again, and they are effectively "logged out" of my system.

I am using Rails 3.0.1 with Devise 1.4.2 for user accounts. The user authorization is passed to a Devise registration (I need to keep track of users in my app - a voting-based "contest" application). Devise uses the "Server side Flow" detailed here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

I'm lost as to what would be causing this. Facebook killing the auth cookie? Does this happen?

Comment: Hi did you ever fix this issue, I have the exact same problem... any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

When you access the facebook tab page first time,signed_request is necessary:
`@signed_request = oauth.parse_signed_request(params[:signed_request])`

So you can send a parameter when redirect to it from other pages to check if it's the first time.